# Getting sklearn's partial fit SGDClassifier coefficients

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to train a logistic regression model using a [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) that I `partial_fit` on mini batches :

```
sgdLogReg = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
for i in range(math.ceil(len(X_train)/mini_batch_size)):
    sgdLogReg.partial_fit(X_train[i*mini_batch_size:(i+1)*mini_batch_size], 
                          Y_train[i*mini_batch_size:(i+1)*mini_batch_size], 
                          classes=[0,1])
```

However, as I am not using the `fit` function, the `sgdLogReg.coef_` attribute is not set :

> AttributeError: 'SGDClassifier' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Is there a way to get the coefficients vector using `partial_fit` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are calling `coef_` before fitting the data. Below example shows that you can get the `coef_` after `.partial_fit`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification()

sgd = SGDClassifier()

sgd.partial_fit(X,y, classes=[0,1])

print(sgd.coef_)

# [[-42.53636525  -2.52884548 -39.11102068 -14.67123492  16.20897739
#   -35.94926059  12.62473266  18.07587488  49.73232778 -16.74330257
#    78.61713294 -22.21668162  14.89044933 -16.34974837   6.38661036
#    18.58266319  18.84123791  28.24578991  37.94146501  21.3143532 ]]
```

Comment: I do the `partial_fit` operation before printing the coefficients, but it still doesn't work. FYI I am using sklearn version 0.21.2 on python 3.7.3

Comment: I am not sure, why u r not getting the result. I am using sklearn 23.0 dev version and python 3.